# PDO json_decode before fetch into class

Tags: php

Is there a way to json parse string before making it a class with PDO? I don't like using union types.

In the example below **contact** is of type json in the database.

PDO

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name, contact FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
```

User class

```
<?php
class User {
   public string $first_name;
   public string $last_name;
   public string | object $contact;

   public function __construct() {
     $this->contact = json_decode($this->contact);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do we assume you have an `$stmt->execute()` in there in the real code?

Comment: What's the result using the current code? When using PDO, the constructor should be called *after* the properties are assigned, so the code you have at the moment looks like it should work - `$this->contact` should be the return value of the `json_decode` call applied to the column value

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly, I edited my question. @Iainn The code I have there, works. It converts the string into json. But I was wondering if there is another way to do it, because I don't like having the string | object type.

Comment: @flowstacker Ah ok, in which case the answer is probably going to be no. The only other approach I can think of would be to use [`PDO::FETCH_FUNC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), which would let you define a callback to instantiate the object instead. But I don't think it would be cleaner than what you have now.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Because at first, the contact column is a string. If i declare only object type, I get error.

Comment: Yea, sorry, small brain fart caused me to ask a silly question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Movahhedi suggested you could use `PDO::FETCH_FUNC`, but the `json_decode()` should take place in the passed function, not in the constructor. My suggestion would be to create a `UserFactory` class with a method like `createFromDbRow()`, although just defining it as a bare function would work just as well too, of course:

```php
class User {
  public string $first_name;
  public string $last_name;
  public object $contact;
}

class UserFactory {
  public function createFromDbRow(string $first_name, string $last_name, string $contact) : User {
    $user = new User();
    $user->first_name = $first_name;
    $user->last_name = $last_name;
    $user->contact = json_decode( $contact );
    
    return $user;
  }
}

$db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE "users" ( "id" INTEGER, "first_name" TEXT, "last_name" TExT, "contact" TEXT )');
$db->exec('INSERT INTO "users" VALUES( 1, \'John\', \'Doe\', \'{"email":"johndoe@example.com"}\')');
$db->exec('INSERT INTO "users" VALUES( 2, \'Jane\', \'Doe\', \'{"email":"janedoe@example.com"}\')');

$userFactory = new UserFactory();

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name, contact FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, [$userFactory, 'createFromDbRow' ]);

var_dump( $users );
```

Since the `User` properties are all public I left out a constructor, but you could of course define a constructor as well:

```php
class User {
  public string $first_name;
  public string $last_name;
  public object $contact;

  public function __construct(string $first_name, string $last_name, object $contact) {
    $this->first_name = $first_name;
    $this->last_name = $last_name;
    $this->contact = $contact;
  }
}
```

...and then create the `User`s in `UserFactory::createFromDbRow()` by utilizing the constructor:

```php
class UserFactory {
  public function createFromDbRow(string $first_name, string $last_name, string $contact) : User {
    return new User(
      $first_name,
      $last_name,
      json_decode( $contact )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FETCH_FUNC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

The function we define actually does what the constructor does

```php
function customConstruct(first_name, $last_name, $contact) {
    return new User($first_name, $last_name, $contact);
}
```

Now we do it

```php
$stmt = $DB->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name, contact FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, "customConstruct");
```

User class

```php
class User {
    public string $first_name;
    public string $last_name;
    public object $contact;

    public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $contact) {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        $this->contact = json_decode($contact);
    }
}
```

if you need an array, use:

```php
$this->contact = json_decode($contact, true);
```

##### EDIT

We maybe able to put the new function in the class. I'm not 100% sure though.

```php
class User {
    public string $first_name;
    public string $last_name;
    public object $contact;

    public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $contact) {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        $this->contact = json_decode($contact);
    }

    function customConstruct(first_name, $last_name, $contact) {
        return new User($first_name, $last_name, $contact);
    }
}
```